# How to draw an octahedral in latex

Tags: commutative-diagrams

I need help drawing the shape of an octahedral in LaTeX witk TikZ, shown below.   Thank you! I start to draw an octahedral but unfortunately;y I don't know how I can put the vertices in it.

[image]

This is what I did

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (0.6,0.2);
\coordinate (A3) at (1,0);
\coordinate (A4) at (0.4,-0.2);
\coordinate (B1) at (0.5,0.5);
\coordinate (B2) at (0.5,-0.5);

\draw[dashed] (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3);
\draw (A1) -- (A4) -- (A3);
\draw[dashed] (B1) -- (A2) -- (B2);
\draw (B1) -- (A4) -- (B2);
\draw (B1) -- (A1) -- (B2) -- (A3) --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Hint: Searching for `commutative diagram` will give you related questions, especially have a look at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd.

Comment: For future reference: it is generally a better idea to add such code directly to your question. Also, you can edit your question at any given time. Not all people read the comments directly.

Comment: Ok thank you so much

Comment: Since this is question is not really about a table, but more so about the creation of a commutative diagram, I edited the tag to reflect on that.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep=huge]
                                 & b' \arrow[dr] \arrow[ddl, squiggly] \arrow[from=ddr, crossing over]                &                                        \\
c' \arrow[ur] \arrow[d,squiggly] &                                                                                    & a' \arrow[ll, squiggly, crossing over] \\
a \arrow[rr] \arrow[dr]          &                                                                                    & c \arrow[u]                            \\
                                 & b \arrow[uul, crossing over] \arrow[ur] \arrow[from=uur, squiggly, crossing over]  &
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much