# Crossing over method with xy package for one or more arrows

Tags: arrows, xy-pic, commutative-diagrams, intersections, xymatrix

Related on this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/601918/how-to-draw-an-octahedral-in-latex), considering the original image,

[image]

adding my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=2pc@C=2.8pc{
& b' \ar@{~>}[ddl]|\hole \ar[dr] & \\
c' \ar@{~>}[d] \ar[ur]  & & \ar@{~>}[ll] a' \ar@{~>}[ddl]|\hole\\
a \ar[rr] \ar[dr]& & c\ar[uul]|\hole \ar[u] \\
& b \ar[ur] \ar[uul]|\hole &
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am not able with `xy` package to hide, through the crossing over method, the same vector as in the initial figure. What is the optimal solution?

Comment: I don't think there's a simple way to do this: `xy` doesn't "know" what the break is breaking; it simply puts the break at the midpoint of the arrow. You can see this by e.g. changing the arrow between *a'* and *b* to be `[dl]`. The result is a completely misplaced break even though the only arrow crossed is the one between *b'* and *c*.

Comment: @AlanMunn Hi very kind Alan: Yes it's true. I remember when I had compiled my code a few weeks ago. But whoever had created the first figure what trick did he use? I am not able. :-(

Comment: It may be able to be done with the `\PATH` construct. (But don't ask me how...) :)

Comment: @AlanMunn aahahahahah LOL :-)....I have seen something two last weeks for this package but I not remember now nothing.